# I want to fix bottom navigation and ads to the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to fix bottom navigation and ads to the bottom. But the picture remains as seen. Can you help me?
My xml code is as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOgw.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Anasayfa"
    tools:ignore="NotSibling">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7657308039754206/7261639976"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/altbottom"
        app:itemIconSize="25dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/itemcolors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: We need your layout file to be able to help.

Comment: I edited it for you

Comment: is this the complete layout file? i can not find bottom_nav

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste the whole xml, but I guess it's just ordering problem.
You need to move the AdView and BottomNavigationView to be last in the file.